# Nginx Passenger on FreeBSD 11.1

Tags: nginx, passenger, freebsd

I can't seem to get `Passenger` loaded on `FreeBSD 11.1` after many retries.  I have `deinstalled` nginx completely.  I've set the config to install `Passenger` and the install says 5.3.4 goes just fine.  I even get this security report:

```
This port has installed the following files which may act as network
servers and may therefore pose a remote security risk to the system.
    /usr/local/sbin/nginx
    /usr/local/libexec/nginx/ngx_http_passenger_module.so
```

Then I test the system for any `Passenger` feedback I can get, knowing it changes every time I try to install it.  I have a `bash` script with the following:

```
    passenger-config --ruby-command
    passenger-config --root
    passenger-config validate-install
    passenger-config system-metrics         
    passenger-config compile-agent  
    passenger-config --make-locations-ini           
    bundle exec passenger-status
    passenger-status
    passenger status
```

With the output:

```
    passenger_help.sh: line 7: passenger-config: command not found
    passenger_help.sh: line 8: passenger-config: command not found
    passenger_help.sh: line 9: passenger-config: command not found
    passenger_help.sh: line 10: passenger-config: command not found
    passenger_help.sh: line 11: passenger-config: command not found
    passenger_help.sh: line 12: passenger-config: command not found
    bundler: command not found: passenger-status
    Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
    passenger_help.sh: line 14: passenger-status: command not found
    passenger_help.sh: line 15: passenger: command not found
```

I expect the `config` to steer the `make` into installing a proper `Passenger`, but it doesn't get installed at all.  Am I to use another package?  Fusion's website doesn't say anything about `FreeBSD` specifically.  I'm at a loss as to how to get this working.

Any advice appreciated how I can get this working properly.  Cheers

Comment: `pkg info -xl passenger` will list all files installed by that package. Try searching there.

Comment: `pkg:  No package(a) matching passenger`

Comment: Maybe you need to install `rubygem-passenger` then?

Comment: That's what I did.  I haven't found any documentation that says I need that.  You'd think that would be up front.

Answer (score 1):

as fare as i use passenger with nginx there is no fully supported pkg.
the following steps are necessary

```
portsnap fetch extract   [or]
portsnap fetch update

cd /usr/ports/www/nginx
make config     # select passenger!
make install clean # is installing nginx with passenger support

# this command installs ruby gem sources
gem install passenger

# change to ruby gem files and compile the nginx module
cd /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/passenger-???
rake nginx:as_dynamic_module
```

then add the following line on top of

```
 # /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

 load_module /usr/local/libexec/nginx/ngx_http_passenger_module.so;

 http {
   passenger_root /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/passenger-5.3.7;
   passenger_ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby;
   passenger_load_shell_envvars off;
   passenger_sticky_sessions on;

   ...
 }
```

and inside a site definition add the following lines

```
 # /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites/default.conf

 server {
   listen 80;
   server_name ... ;

   passenger_enabled on;
   passenger_min_instances 1;
   rails_app_spawner_idle_time 0;
   # rails_env development;

   ...

}
```

Comment: I gave up on FreeBSD.

Comment: i love it :) nothing better than that.